# jsbn2 modInverse returns undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, biginteger

I have found this library for big integers called jsbn2 by Tom Wu, 
and it seemed to work well until I had to use modInverse method.
For some reason it returns **undefined** no matter what.
The method in the library is:

```
bnModInverse(m) {
    var ac = m.isEven();
    if((this.isEven() && ac) || m.signum() == 0) return  new BigInteger(0);
    var u = m.clone(), v = this.clone();
    var a = new BigInteger(1), b = new BigInteger(0), c = new BigInteger(0), d = new BigInteger(1);
    while(u.signum() != 0) {
        while(u.isEven()) {
        u.rShiftTo(1,u);
        if(ac) {
            if(!a.isEven() || !b.isEven()) { a.addTo(this,a); b.subTo(m,b); }
            a.rShiftTo(1,a);
        }
        else if(!b.isEven()) b.subTo(m,b);
        b.rShiftTo(1,b);
        }
        while(v.isEven()) {
        v.rShiftTo(1,v);
        if(ac) {
            if(!c.isEven() || !d.isEven()) { c.addTo(this,c); d.subTo(m,d); }
            c.rShiftTo(1,c);
        }
        else if(!d.isEven()) d.subTo(m,d);
        d.rShiftTo(1,d);
        }
        if(u.compareTo(v) >= 0) {
        u.subTo(v,u);
        if(ac) a.subTo(c,a);
        b.subTo(d,b);
        }
        else {
        v.subTo(u,v);
        if(ac) c.subTo(a,c);
        d.subTo(b,d);
        }
    }
    if(v.compareTo( BigInteger.ONE ) != 0) return  new BigInteger(0);
    if(d.compareTo(m) >= 0) return d.subtract(m);
    if(d.signum() < 0) d.addTo(m,d); else return d;
    // MODIFIED BY ATS 2008/11/22 FOR COMPATIBILITY TO Flash ActionScript
    // if(d.signum() < 0) return d.add(m); else return d;
    if(d.signum() < 0) return d.ope_add(m); else return d;
    };
```

I used it with very long numbers, for ex.

```
var a = new BigInteger("26243431849380303664210129223718904471391758038739441955848319764858899645035");
var b = new BigInteger("fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffc2f", 16);
```

*(fixed b value, ty Rudy Velthuis)*

But the `a.modInverse(b)` returns undefined.

Is there something wrong with the method, that needs to be fixes?
How can I make it work?

Comment: I didn't try to follow the code, but the numbers you show are not coprime, and can not be inverted. Their gcd is (obviously) 5.

Comment: yeah, I showed bad example.. 
from the code that I'm using in .modInverse() would be BigInteger("fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffc2f",16)
(it is Prime)
Sorry for misleading you.  Btw, the exact same code and numbers WORK in java with their library.. I get this problem only in JavaScript =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. after like hundreds of logs and stuff I finally found what is the problem in my case.
While the example value that I gave in question itself seems to actually work, there is a different problem with the method modInverse (again.. sorry if that mislead someone).

The problem with it (the modInverse method in jsbn2) is that it doesn't know what to do with **negative** numbers (while the Java modInverse knows).

My solution to this was to check if the value that I will give it is positive and if not, I prepared it (thanks to [this topic for explaining how](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519845/modulo-of-a-negative-number)):

```
if(a.compareTo(ZERO)<0)
{
 a = a.negate();  //make it positive
 a = a.mod(b);    //get modulo
 a = b.subtract(a);  //get remainder of modulo
}
```

I don't know if this is the best solution to it (surely not) but it seems to work.
The result values that I tested are now equal to those of Java's modInverse.

Hope this helps anyone who get lost just like me here :3